# IF statement in background image in a Picture box

Tags: vb.net, vba, picturebox

I have 2 images in my Project's Resources and I want to make an If statement to see if a picture box has one, if that happens, I want to change to another image. I have something like this but it does not work:

```
 If  pic1.BackgroundImage Is Global.images.My.Resources.ima1 Then
 pic1.BackgroundImage = Global.images.My.Resources.ima2
End If
```

Am I right? or what else can I do to it to get that?

Comment: Maybe `If  pic1.BackgroundImage = Global.images.My.Resources.ima1 Then` or `If  pic1.BackgroundImage.Equals(Global.images.My.Resources.ima1) Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If  pic1.BackgroundImage = Global.images.My.Resources.ima1 Then
 pic1.BackgroundImage = Global.images.My.Resources.ima2
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    If IsNothing(pic.BackgroundImage) Then
        pic.BackgroundImage = simple.My.Resources.Resources.Winter
    End If
```